# CMake Cross Compile - Header not found

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, cross-compiling

I am trying to do a cross compile build with CMake for the first time.
The project structure looks like this:

```
- myproject/
|- toolchain.cmake
|- tmproot/
|- app/
 |- myapp/
  |- CMakeLists.txt
|- lib/
 |- mylib1/
  |- CMakeLists.txt
 |- mylib2/
  |- CMakeLists.txt
 |- mylib3/
  |- CMakeLists.txt
 |- spdlog/
  |- CMakeLists.txt
 |- json/
  |- CMakeLists.txt
```

The toolchain.cmake looks like this:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
 
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  <path to myproject>/tmproot) 

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER            $ENV{XILINX_VITIS}/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER          $ENV{XILINX_VITIS}/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)

set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE "STATIC_LIBRARY")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

spdlog and json are external libs. My own libs (partially) depend on each other and on the external libs.

I am able to build and install all of the libs with the following commands:

```
/usr/bin/cmake $PWD -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="../../toolchain.cmake"
make DESTDIR="$PWD/../../tmproot" install
```

After that all the libs are located in `<path to myproject>/tmproot/usr/local/lib` and the headers in `myproject>/tmproot/usr/local/include/<lib_name>`
When building the libs I see the following text in the compiler call: `-isystem <path to myproject>/tmproot/usr/local/include` and the compiler finds all required headers.

But when I try to build the application (which needs all the libs) with the same toolchain settings I don't see the `-isystem` output and the compiler complains about missing headers.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is here?

**Edit:**

I created a minimal example with the following structure:

```
- myproject/
|- toolchain.cmake
|- tmproot/
|- app/
 |- app1/
  |- CMakeLists.txt
  |- app1.cpp
|- lib/
 |- lib1/
  |- CMakeLists.txt
  |- lib1.cpp
  |- lib1.h
 |- lib2/
  |- CMakeLists.txt
  |- lib2.cpp
  |- lib2.h
```

The toolchain.cmake is the same as above.

lib1:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(lib1 LANGUAGES CXX C)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
set(CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX "")
add_library (lib1 lib1.cpp lib1.h)
install(FILES lib1.h DESTINATION include/lib1 COMPONENT Development)
install (TARGETS lib1
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${BINDIR} COMPONENT Applications
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${LIBDIR} COMPONENT Libraries
)
```

```
#ifndef LIB1_H
#define LIB1_H
int lib1_func(int param);
#endif
```

```
int lib1_func(int param)
{
    return param+42;
}
```

lib2:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(lib2 LANGUAGES CXX C)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

set(CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX "")

add_library (lib2 lib2.cpp lib2.h)

target_link_libraries (lib2 PUBLIC lib1)

install(FILES lib2.h DESTINATION include/lib2 COMPONENT Development)
install (TARGETS lib2
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${BINDIR} COMPONENT Applications
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${LIBDIR} COMPONENT Libraries
)
```

```
#ifndef LIB2_H
#define LIB2_H
int lib2_func(int param);
#endif
```

```
#include "lib1/lib1.h"
int lib2_func(int param)
{
    return param+lib1_func(param);
}
```

app1:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(app1 LANGUAGES CXX C)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

add_executable (app1 "app1.cpp")
target_link_libraries(app1 PUBLIC lib1 PUBLIC lib2)
```

```
#include "lib1/lib1.h"
#include "lib2/lib2.h"


int main()
{
    return lib1_func(1) + lib2_func(2);
}
```

With this example, I don't even get as far as described above. Already lib2 cannot be built.

Steps to reproduce:

```
cd lib/lib1
/usr/bin/cmake $PWD -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="../../toolchain.cmake"
make DESTDIR="$PWD/../../tmproot" install
cd ../lib2
/usr/bin/cmake $PWD -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="../../toolchain.cmake"
make
fatal error: lib1/lib1.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "lib1/lib1.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
ls ../../tmproot/usr/local/include/lib1/
lib1.h
```

Comment: "But when I try to build the application (which needs all the libs) with the same toolchain settings I don't see the `-isystem` output and the compiler complains about missing headers." - Probably, something wrong with your application and its `CMakeLists.txt`. Please, provide [mcve].

Comment: Try [`target_include_directories(libX PUBLIC .)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) in the libraries' respective CMakeLists.

Comment: That works, of course. But I want to avoid these entries in the CMakeLists, also because the target is to be built in different contexts (hardware/simulation/unit tests, ...). That is actually the reason why I install the lib in a place where the compiler normally searches automatically.